# For a smooth projective variety $X \subset \mathbf{P}$, why is the normal bundle $N_{X/\mathbf{P}}(-1)$ globally generated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding the proof that $K_X + (n + 1)B$ is globally generated when $X$ is a smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ and $B$ is very ample. For context, I'm reading this from Rob Lazarsfeld's Positivity II, remark 10.4.5. The idea is that this divisor is associated to the top wedge power of the twisted normal bundle $N_{X/\mathbf{P}}(-1)$ of the embedding given by $B$. Now it is claimed that since $N_{X/\mathbf{P}}(-1)$ is a quotient of $T_{\mathbf{P}}(-1)|_X$ which is globally generated, it follows that $N_{X/\mathbf{P}}(-1)$ is globally generated as well.

I am having trouble understanding how we can justify this last step. We have the usual exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow T_X(-1) \longrightarrow T_{\mathbf{P}}|_X(-1) \longrightarrow N_{X/\mathbf{P}}(-1) \longrightarrow 0$$ so to show $N_{X/\mathbf{P}}(-1)$ is globally generated, it suffices to show that the induced map $H^0(X, T_{\mathbf{P}}|_X(-1)) \to H^0(X, N_{X/\mathbf{P}}(-1))$ is surjective, and for this it suffices to show $H^1(X, T_X(-1)) = 0$. However, I am not sure how to get this vanishing. This proof is supposed to work in all characteristics so I'm hoping to avoid Kodaira vanishing or Hodge theory, and I suspect Serre duality might be useful but I don't see how to apply it.

Any help for showing this surjectivity would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the surjectivity on $H^0$. Just note that there is a composition of surjective morphisms
$$
\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n+1} \to 
T_{\mathbb{P}^n}\vert_X(-1) \to 
N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}(-1),
$$
hence the composition is surjective, and this means that $N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)$ is globally generated.